# Create bar chart only using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, bar-chart

I once saw a MySQL result where one fetched amount was displayed with `*` as bar charts. Something like this.

```
id | amount | bar
----------------------------
 1 |      7 | *******
 2 |      4 | ****
 3 |      0 | 
 4 |      3 | ***
 5 |      9 | *********
 6 |     10 | **********
 7 |      6 | ******
 8 |      3 | ***
 9 |      2 | **
 10|      0 |
```

If I remember correctly, it was some kind of `RANGE()` function that was used in the query, like

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    COUNT(*) AS `amount`,
    RANGE(`amount`) AS `bar`
FROM
    `table`
```

But I was neither successful researching on google or SO. Anyone knows how to do this or can forward me to the appropriate SO post?

Comment: http://www.css-resources.com/Make-Bar-Chart-from-MySQL-Table-Data.html

Comment: You can do that with REPEAT().

Comment: @SujithKarivelil I don't want to use PHP. I want to use a MySQL query exclusively.

Comment: @Strawberry `REPEAT()`, it was `REPEAT()`! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) had the clue [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839581/create-bar-chart-only-using-mysql-query#comment38567761_24839581). The function's name I was looking for is `REPEAT()`. I funnily couldn't find it in the MySQL documentation, so I'm referring to [w3resource](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-repeat-function.php) (if anyone can find official docu, feel free to edit).

> ## Syntax
>
> ```
> REPEAT(str, count)
> ```
>
> - `str` A string which is to be repeated.
> - `count` An integer indicating how many times the string str is to be repeated.

So the function can be used like this

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    COUNT(*) AS `amount`,
    REPEAT('#' , COUNT(`amount`)) AS `bar`
FROM
    `table`
```

Which returns an ouput like

```
id | amount | bar
----------------------------
 1 |      4 | ####
 2 |     14 | ##############
 3 |      8 | ########
 4 |      5 | #####
 5 |      3 | ###
 6 |     11 | ###########
```

The `count` parameter can also be used to stretch or shrink the bar, e.g. by multiplication - or division, like this

```
...
  REPEAT('#', COUNT(`amount`)/4)) AS `bar`
...
```

would return things like this

```
id | amount | bar
----------------------
 1 |     20 | #####
 2 |     12 | ###
 3 |     32 | ########
```